# How to compare the year to timestamp date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to take all the records from a specific year.
My table is `race_details` and the year is a part of the date in race_date (in unix timestamp)

```
SELECT * 
FROM race_details AS r 
WHERE r.race_date=(SELECT MAX(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(race_date))) 
                   FROM race_details)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's more to the problem, I think you're overcomplicating your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM race_details AS r 
WHERE YEAR(race_date) = 2014;
```

Substitute `2014` for the year to look up, and if it's a variable, remember to parameterize!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the year of the `race_date`, not the whole `race_date`:

```
WHERE YEAR(race_date) = (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have column race_date in 2 tables and I need to specify r.YEAR(race_date) but it doesn't work

Comment: It should be `YEAR(r.race_date)`.